# how to foreach all controllers and actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

as titled

i'd like use syntax like this:

```
allControllers.Find(x=>x.Name=="HomeController")
```

i want to add a attribute to an action using LINQ when application start

Comment: you can check :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880388/asp-net-mvc-get-all-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use reflection to get all controllers. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680609/reflect-over-list-of-controllers) link could help. And then use reflection to get instances of that types (see Activator).